# Records added to ms access database with vb 2010 not saving

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a simple data logging program, and I have little to no database experience.  I wrote a little VB forms app to log the data to ms access and then graph the data, but I'm having trouble with adding records to the database.

First, I created a simple one table database in access.  Then, I added the database to the project as a data source, and gave it a data set using the wizard.  Right now my code looks like this:

```
Public Class mainForm

Dim da As New dsTableAdapters.Sensor_DataTableAdapter
```

...

My database consists of table simply called Sensor_Data.  My data set is simply Ds which was created when I added the database as a data source.  I call the updAccess() subroutine whenever new data arrives.  Please ignore the switch case.  It is for future functionality.

...

```
Private Sub updAccess(ByVal data() As String)
    Select Case data(0)
        Case "001"
            Ds.Sensor_Data.Clear()
            da.Fill(Ds.Sensor_Data)

            Dim dsNewRow As DataRow = Ds.Sensor_Data.NewSensor_DataRow

            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 1") = data(1)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 2") = data(2)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 3") = data(3)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 4") = data(4)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 5") = data(5)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 6") = data(6)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 7") = data(7)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 8") = data(8)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 9") = data(9)
            dsNewRow.Item("Sensor 10") = data(10)

            Ds.Sensor_Data.AddSensor_DataRow(dsNewRow)
            da.Update(Ds.Sensor_Data)

        Case "002"
            'TODO: update settings panel
    End Select
End Sub
```

...

There are no problems during build or run time, but I do not see changes to database after the program runs.  Any input is greatly appreciated.  Also, any recommended reference material is also welcomed.

Comment: da.Fill(Ds.Sensor_Data,"tablename")

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?  I get a syntax error with that command.  Also I have verified the current fill line does populate the data set with relevant data.

Comment: Hi Casbar, Does `DS` have a connection string to your access DB. from the code you are showing it appears you are creating a new data row that is not connected to anything.

Comment: The connection string was shown when I ran the wizard that set up Ds, but at no point do I enter the connection string in my code. How and when does that information need to be entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several weeks of pulling out my hair.  The database was being updated fine, but I wasn't looking at the copy of the database in the bin\debug folder.  Oh well.  Now I know.