# Is there a quick way to update an access table using vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to copy a datatable from a vb.net form I've set up into an access database. I'm using a snippet of code (with some alterations) posted by another user (Casbar27, [Records added to ms access database with vb 2010 not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762257/records-added-to-ms-access-database-with-vb-2010-not-saving)).

```
    Back_EndDataSet.tblTest.Clear()
    Dim adapter As New Back_EndDataSetTableAdapters.tblTestTableAdapter
    Dim rowCode As DataRow = Back_EndDataSet.tblTest.NewtblTestRefreshxinRow

    For Each row As DataRow In source.Rows
        adapter.Fill(Back_EndDataSet.tblTest)

        rowCode.Item(0) = row.Item(0)
        rowCode.Item(1) = row.Item(1)
        rowCode.Item(2) = row.Item(2)
        rowCode.Item(3) = row.Item(3)
        rowCode.Item(4) = row.Item(4)
        rowCode.Item(5) = row.Item(5)
        rowCode.Item(6) = row.Item(6)
        rowCode.Item(7) = row.Item(7)
        rowCode.Item(8) = row.Item(8)
        rowCode.Item(9) = row.Item(9)
        Back_EndDataSet.tblTest.AddtblTestRow(rowCode)


        adapter.Update(Back_EndDataSet.tblTest)
    Next
```

While this is working, it's slow and is producing multiples of the same record if it's run several times. I want this to wipe the access table on start and rewrite it, and preferably in under a minute. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try doing the `.Fill` before entering the loop and the `.Update` after exiting the loop. As for emptying the table, you could always just use an OleDbCommand object to run a `DELETE FROM TableName` statement before you start working with the TableAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Gord Thompson's suggestion I wrote an `OleDbCommand` to delete the table, and decided to keep going an rewrote my filling method using an `OleDbCommand`. It work's great, the completion speed is up and I no longer have duplicate records. Thanks Gord!

```
Private Sub UpdateDataBase(ByVal source As DataTable)
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= H:\AppDev\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RawFixerTest1\Raw Fixer Back End.accdb")
    Dim cmdClr As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdFill As New OleDbCommand
    Dim i = 0

    con.Open()
    cmdClr.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM tblTestRefreshxin"
    cmdClr.Connection = con
    cmdClr.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmdFill.Connection = con
    For Each row As DataRow In source.Rows
        cmdFill.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTestRefreshxin (numCode, featDesc, alphaCode, clientCode, DTMexclude, attrCode1, attrCode2, attrCode3, attrCode4, lineToPrev) VALUES(" & "'" & row.Item(0) & "','" & row.Item(1) & "','" & row.Item(2) & "','" & row.Item(3) & "','" & row.Item(4) & "','" & row.Item(5) & "','" & row.Item(6) & "','" & row.Item(7) & "','" & row.Item(8) & "','" & row.Item(9) & "')"
        cmdFill.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    con.Close()
End Sub
```